# Automation Hub collections by AWX

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-galaxy, ansible-collections

On my AWX System I've configure *collection* in `requirement.yml` and all is fine.

Now, I need to insert another collection providing by **Automation Hub**. That's means the source is in another place. I've read this document [Downloading a collection from Automation Hub](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy/user_guide.html#id9) but unfortunately it doesn't run. I've create an `ansible.cfg` in my role directory but perhaps it is not the right way.

By AWX is not possibly to configure it through WebUI like Ansible Tower.

As anyone any idea how to resolve this?

Where's define the ansible.cfg by AWX and is it possible to configure many?

Best regards,
H.